# Dynamic pattern validation in Angular 2 and 4

Tags: validation, angular

Input validation works fine with a fixed pattern, e.g.

```
<input type="number"
    [(ngModel)]="info.sortOrder"
    pattern="[0-9][0-9]"
    id="sortOrder" name="sortOrder" #sortOrder="ngModel"/>
```

When changing the pattern to be evaluated through a function, validation always fails. The function "customPattern()" is called, though.

```
<input type="number"
    [(ngModel)]="info.sortOrder"
    [pattern]="customPattern()"
    id="sortOrder" name="sortOrder" #sortOrder="ngModel"/>
```

With

```
customPattern() { return "[1-9][0-9]"; }
```

Is this a bug or is this not supposed to work this way?

Comment: this can be easily achieve by switching to model driven form.

Comment: for having dynamic pattern for template driven form, you could create a directive like shown in [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are dong wrong, @black
I would recommend you to use Reactive Forms approach to achieve the desire result.

1. create a reactive form.
2. Add the control name for eg('number_validation').
3. (optional) Register the HTML input element with the formControlName same as above ('number_validation').
4. create a field 'regex' = '[0-9][0-9]' in the component.ts file.
5. Bind the [pattern] = regex in the HTML HTML input element tag.
6. Listen the change and change the regex pattern according to the requirement.

In ts file.

```
 someForm: FormGroup;

this.someForm= new FormGroup({
        'some_name': new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required])});

regex = /[0-9][0-9]/;
```

In HTML:

```
 <input type="number"
    [pattern]=regex
    id="sortOrder"
    formControlName=some_name 
    name="sortOrder"/>
```

Logic :

It depends on the requirement how you are going to change the regex value, dynamically.
eg.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someForm.get('some_name').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      if (val === 'anything') {
        this.regex = /change the regex/;
      } else if (val === 'anything_other') {
        this.regex = /change the regex/;
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope it help you, or other devs! :)

Answer (score 0):

In reactive forms you could easily do this:

```
let regPattern = ...; // some logic to determine regex
let lastUsedRegexValidator = Validators.pattern(regPattern);
this.someService.myControl.addValidators(lastUsedRegexValidator)
```

and in .HTML to check whether we have error:

```
<div *ngIf="someService.myControl.errors['pattern']">Pattern error occurred.</div>
```

Make sure to remove validators when you don't need them anymore before adding new ones, so you don't end up in a situation with a lot of unneeded validators being added.

```
this.someService.myControl.removeValidators(this.lastUsedRegexValidator)

// for some reason removing like this is not working
this.someService.myControl.removeValidators(Validators.pattern(regPattern))
```

Answer (score -2):

In you component, simply define a member variable like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
 customPattern = '[1-9][0-9]';
```

In your html, use interpolation like this:

```
pattern = "{{customPattern}}"
```

That should work.

Comment: Tell me what is the reason to use string interpolation here? we don't need to show the pattern on DOM?